# Blender Cloth Physics - Limit Object Collisions to several collections

Tags: objects, cloth-simulation, collision, collections

is it possible to limit the object collision of a cloth to more than one collection. I can only select one collection. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. But you can create a new collection where you put all your collision objects in.

Comment: Hmm too bad. I would have done that otherwise, but the problem is that I can't divide it up accordingly because I have a lot of objects, some of which have different requirements.

Comment: Objects can belong to multiple collections.  So if you need x to collide with A and B, but y to collide with B and C, then you can have collections xCollide{A,B} and yCollide{B,C} just fine.  And any other collection memberships of A, B, or C will remain unaffected.

Comment: Oh yes that would be great but how can a object belong to multiple collections? 
I have to put it in a specific collection or do I have a mistake?

Comment: I can make it with Shift + M :)